# SQL Query Error: Unclosed Quote

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

I am trying to run a sql command:

> SELECT *FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'active_plugins';

However I only get an error that there is an unclosed quote @ 45. I am not sure what is happening as there doesn't seem to be any confusing extra quotes. Is my syntax wrong? I am using mysql 5.1.

Comment: If you copied the query  fromsome place the queots  might  be formatted.  try to remove them and add them again.

Comment: I tried this, still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

You need a space between the asterisk (*) and the word "FROM".

Comment: You don't actually. Just tested this.

SELECT *FROM WebsiteNames WHERE Name = 'Nemos Seafood Buffet';
 Found rows: 1

Comment: Wow!  Thanks for the enlightenment!

Answer (score 1):

try this variation:

```
Select * from wp_options where option_name = "active_plugins";
```

Comment: I tried this, the same error is appearing, but with /"/ triggering it.